# Making python libraries installed as root accessible by other non-root users

Tags: python, installation, root, system-administration

I'm not a sys admin guy, but I am tasked (due to budget limitations) to set up a VM server for a web app. I did my best to figure most things out, but when I try to install Python modules as root, I cannot use them in other non-root accounts that I created.

For example, I installed [Twilio python library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install) as root. But when I log in as "userjoe" and try to run a sample script using twilio, it doesn't work.

What should I do to make libraries installed as root accessible by non-root users? Thank you.

p.s. I'm tagging this post as "python" and a few other in case someone from that community knows the answer. Please let me know if my tags are irrelevant.

Comment: First, did you install them into the system site-packages, or into the root user's user site-packages? Second, what does "it doesn't work" mean? Does it not find the modules, can it not read them when it finds them, or what? (Please post what you actually typed and the traceback, rather than trying to describe it vaguely.)

Comment: We don't know how you installed it in the first place.

Comment: Also, sysadmin-type questions usually belong on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), not Stack Overflow. It's _possible_ that this is a Python-specific installation problem, since you haven't given us enough information to know what's going wrong and where, but if it's not, you won't find help here.

Comment: Hi, @abarnert, I'm not sure how to check if I installed it in system site-packages. I used "$ pip install twilio" as root to install the twilio module. When I'm running the script that uses twilio library as root, it works. But when I try to run the same python script as, say, "joeshmoe", it says, "No module named 'twilio.rest'" (shown below)
[joe@m3 test]$ python send_sms.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_sms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
ImportError: No module named twilio.rest
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'll edit/update the tag as appropriate. Please let me know if you think it should belong to SuperUser strictly.

Comment: One thing to test: As root, `import twilio.rest`, then `print twilio.rest.__file__`. If it's something starting with `/usr/lib/python2.X/site-packages/` or similar, that's system site-packages; if it's something starting with `/root` or `/home/root` or similar, that's root's user site-packages.

Comment: And then, once you know the path, as joeschmoe, in bash, try `ls -l /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/__init__.py`. If you get a permissions error, or it succeeds but shows that the file isn't world-readable, then that's the problem (and then you have a SuperUser problem).

Comment: Thank you for clear step-by-step instructions, @abarnert! As root, it's `/usr/lib/python2.X/site-packages/`. As joeschmoe, I see `[joeschmoe@m3 test]$ ls -l /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twilio/rest/__init__.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 6966 Jan 13 04:15 /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twilio/rest/__init__.py

I guess it's world-redeable. What should I do next to solve the problem? Still post this on SuperUser?

Comment: Next step is, as both root and joeschmoe, from Python, `import sys` and `print sys.path`. This will be pretty long, so don't post the whole thing here… but do make sure that `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages` is included for both. If not, that's the problem we have to figure out. If so… on to the next possibility. (I'll be sleeping, but hopefully with enough information someone else can help you.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45146/discussion-between-user1330974-and-abarnert)

Answer (score 2):

If the Python module is only used by a single user, you could login with that user (userjoe) and use the `--user` parameter of PIP to install it into the user's home directory:

```
pip install twilio --user
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I logged in as "userjoe" and did what you described. I got:
[userjoe@m3 test]$ pip install twilio --user
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twilio in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2>=0.7 in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from twilio)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from twilio)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): unittest2 in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from twilio)
Cleaning up...

Comment: I tried using twilio in python and got same error as mentioned above. What should I do then? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user1330974 forgot to mention that the module should removed at first with root user `pip uninstall twilio` and then login as userjoe to run the above command.

Comment: thank you. I did just what you recommended. Still got the same error. `Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled twilio
[root@m3 ~]# exit
logout
[userjoe@m3 test]$ pip install twilio --user
Downloading/unpacking twilio
  Downloading twilio-3.6.4.tar.gz (147kB): 147kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_userjoe/twilio/setup.py) egg_info for package twilio
Requirement already satisfied...`

Comment: @user1330974 `Requirement already satisfied` is only a notice, not an error. At the end you should see `Successfully installed twilio`

Comment: Thank you, @andpei! Weird enough, I didn't see "Successfully installed twilio", and it wasn't working when I try to use it as joeschmoe. So I gave up, logged out and went to bed. 8 hours later, I logged in as "userjoe" and now twilio library is available for that user! So your approach works as a temporary fix! :) I'm upvoting your answer, but would wait for someone else to tell me how to make libraries installed by root accessible by non-root users. If you know how to do that, please share your knowledge. Thank you again.